# How to get correct numerical integration which should be zero?

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to numerically integrate function `berrycur` over kx and ky. The definition of `berrycur` is given at the end of the question. 
The plot of `berrycur[kx,ky,1]` is shown as follows:

[image]

and numerical integration

```
NIntegrate[
 berrycur[kx, ky, 1], {kx, -((2 \π)/Sqrt[3]), (2 \π)/Sqrt[3]}, {ky, 0, (4 \π)/3}]
```

gives error message

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly;
>   suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is
>   0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>

The correct answer should be zero. Since the function is abnormal at some places, the error message is forgivable.

Then I define another function `berrycurtmp` which is

```
berrycursum[kx_?NumericQ, ky_?NumericQ] = 
 berrycur[kx, ky, 1] + berrycur[kx, ky, 2]
```

the plot of `berrycursum` is smooth now as shown in

[image]

But the numerical integration

```
NIntegrate[
     berrycur[kx, ky, 1], {kx, -((2 \π)/Sqrt[3]), (2 \π)/Sqrt[3]}, {ky, 0, (4 \π)/3}]
```

still gives error message

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly;
>   suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is
>   0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>

**why? And how could we get the correct answer zero?? And how to speed up this numerical integration?**

---

The definition of `berrycur` is here

```
Clear[h]
h[kx_, ky_] := {{0.01` + 
     0.1` (-4 Cos[1.5` ky] Sin[0.8660254037844386` kx] + 
        2 Sin[1.7320508075688772` kx]), 
    1 + 2 Cos[0.8660254037844386` kx] Cos[1.5` ky] - 
     2 I Cos[0.8660254037844386` kx] Sin[1.5` ky], 0, 
    0}, {1 + 2 Cos[0.8660254037844386` kx] Cos[1.5` ky] + 
     2 I Cos[0.8660254037844386` kx] Sin[1.5` ky], -0.01` - 
     0.1` (-4 Cos[1.5` ky] Sin[0.8660254037844386` kx] + 
        2 Sin[1.7320508075688772` kx]), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0.01` - 0.1` (-4 Cos[1.5` ky] Sin[0.8660254037844386` kx] + 
        2 Sin[1.7320508075688772` kx]), 
    1 + 2 Cos[0.8660254037844386` kx] Cos[1.5` ky] - 
     2 I Cos[0.8660254037844386` kx] Sin[1.5` ky]}, {0, 0, 
    1 + 2 Cos[0.8660254037844386` kx] Cos[1.5` ky] + 
     2 I Cos[0.8660254037844386` kx] Sin[1.5` ky], -0.01` + 
     0.1` (-4 Cos[1.5` ky] Sin[0.8660254037844386` kx] + 
        2 Sin[1.7320508075688772` kx])}};
dim = Length@h[1, 1];

Clear[hpar1, hpar2];
hpar1[kx_, ky_] = D[h[kx, ky], kx];
hpar2[kx_, ky_] = D[h[kx, ky], ky];

Clear[purifyeigs];
purifyeigs[eigs_] := 
  Transpose@Sort@Transpose@{Re[eigs[[1]]], eigs[[2]]};

berrycur[kxkx_?NumericQ, kyky_?NumericQ, i_] := Module[{eigs},
  eigs = purifyeigs@Eigensystem[h[kxkx, kyky]];
  Im@Sum[((Conjugate[eigs[[2, i]]].hpar1[kxkx, kyky].eigs[[2, 
           j]])*(Conjugate[eigs[[2, j]]].hpar2[kxkx, kyky].eigs[[2, 
           i]]) - (Conjugate[eigs[[2, i]]].hpar2[kxkx, kyky].eigs[[2, 
           j]])*(Conjugate[eigs[[2, j]]].hpar1[kxkx, kyky].eigs[[2, 
           i]]))/(eigs[[1, i]] - eigs[[1, j]])^2, {j, 
     DeleteCases[Range[1, dim], i]}]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's numeric integration. So it has no means of "knowing" the correct result is zero. In the process error estimates will be formed and if they are larger than the estimated result, this is a problem. But of course they must be larger since the actual result is zero.

The way to tame this is to specify an `AccuracyGoal` that is attainable using the given precision of the input. That way `NIntegrate` might be convinced to give up gracefully once error estimates show the accuracy (in the sense of Mathematica's documentation for `Accuracy`, that is, number of correct digits to right of decimal point) has been attained.

```
NIntegrate[berrycur[kx, ky, 1], {kx, -((2 \[Pi])/Sqrt[3]), (2 \[Pi])/Sqrt[3]},
 {ky, 0, (4 \[Pi])/3}, AccuracyGoal -> 12]

(* Out[352]= -3.80551771684*10^-14 *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `AccuracyGoal` works perfectly